# What are the networking requirements for AirPrint?

Tags: ios, network, airprint

I'm trying to get AirPrint setup at work.  I've used it at home with AirPrint Activator with no problems.  But it doesn't seem to work on my work network.

I suspect our network is too locked down to allow this.  But I haven't been able to find any documentation that specifically outlines the requirements for AirPrint in terms of ports required, etc.  I need to be able to give my network admin something concrete in terms of what he needs to do to open this up for me.

Does such a document exist?  Or can someone at least give me pointers on what needs to be opened up?

Comment: I don't really have enough solid information to provide an answer but things to consider are if the network supports the *Bonjour* protocol (ports for that should be documented), are printers available on the wireless subnet, etc. I'll keep digging. Meanwhile, good luck!

Comment: I finally got this working, but it would still be nice if this were better documented by Apple.  Anyone trying to use AirPrint in a reasonably locked down corporate environment seems likely to run into problems.

Comment: Please document what you did in the form of an answer to your question. In regards to locked down environments, it would seem incumbent on the network support staff, not the "user", to solve this problem (assuming they want to allow AirPrint to begin with) but I agree that better documentation would help.

Comment: AirPrint Activator requires TCP open on port 19631. FWIW, I could never get it working for SNL Server.

Answer (score 1):

AirPrint only works with AirPrint compatible printers, unless you have special software to connect to the printer running on a machine the printer is locally connected to. A great solution for a work environment is the [xPrintServer](http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/mobile-print-servers/xprintserver.html). It's a network adapter that attaches via ethernet to your network and is supposed to make any printer on the network it's attached to AirPrint compatible. It's available for preorder now. I'd partner with your network administrator to see if this is something that is right for your workplace.

Comment: I just got my xPrintServer in the mail and it works great.

Comment: The xPrintServer is great - Lantronix has been making devices like that for ages.

Answer (score 1):

Googling, I saw varying lists of ports to allow ***AirPrint*** connectivity and wanted an objective answer.  So I packet sniffed the interface my ***AirPrint*** print job was made on (*image is a screen-grab from a **MikroTik***).  Would appear the client (**192.168.4.49**) connects from a dynamic port range IP to the printer (**192.168.3.67**) on port ***TCP/631***.  Obviously allow ***Bonjour*** on ***UDP/5353*** for those on a flat network:

[image: Sniff of IF print AirPrint request made on]

Comment: Okey, I confirm this, At present I am port forwarding: 631, 9100, from the "kinda-WAN" to the "LAN", and it works with airPrint.

Answer (score 0):

The two devices must be on the same network segment. Broadcast traffic is used by the bonjour service to discover connected printers when iOS asks around to find any printers advertising service.

Yes - you can have advanced routing where multicast packets get sent to remote printers, but in the simple case, devices simply need to be on the same VLAN and be able to talk amongst themselves when it's time to print.

Answer (score 0):

On a Aruba Network infrastructure with Mobility controller or Instant Access Point, there is a feature called AirGroup that will route across VLAN the mdns traffic for the bonjour services. It will act as a gateway where you can create rules to manage who can access what, when, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows environment, download and install Window AirPrint Installer (**Windows AirPrint Installer iOS 5 for x86 x64**).  It has a register file that needs to be installed, either 32-bit and 64-bit versions (depending on what kind of Windows OS is running, 32-bit or 64-bit).  Follow the instructions.  It allows non-AirPrint printers connected to a Windows machine (Windows XP to Windows 10) to receive and print documents as an AirPrint destination from your Apple device (iOS).  You also need to download and install a Bonjour services package from Apple.

For the firewall, the following ports need to be open:

```
Inbound TCP traffic to port 631 on the Windows machine
Inbound UDP traffic to port 5353 on the Windows machine
Inbound TCP traffic to port 5354 on the Windows machine
```

Print in good health from your iOS device

Answer (score 0):

Hokey, today (check the date of the post), I managed it.

This particular setup is a bit more complex then the question, but it
should show the answer. Short(*): as the previous post, open port 631.
(*) the port might not be enough, depending on your network set up.

Here is one example.

I have:
1 router to connect to the internet (mikro)(a mikrotik on network 192.168.100.0/24)
1 router for home computers (cave)(bluecave set up as router on: 192.168.2.0/24)
1 router for home devices (turris)(turris omina on 192.168.1.0/24)

I need computers from "cave" to print on a wifi printer on "turris".

First i needed to have the printer to get a fixed IP on the turris.
(on turris it is easy to fix the IP), you need to do the same on your router.
Let's assume: 192.168.1.111 (printer)

Then I needed to fix the IP of the turris versus the mikro.
(again the same, mikro I got it), you need to do the same on your main router.
Let's assume: 192.168.100.222 (turris)

On the turris I port forwarded 9100 and 631 to 192.168.1.111.

The "computers" should be able to see the printer at the 192.168.100.222.

So the answer is(*): open port 631.

But as you see it depends a bit on your setup.

- I am not sure if 9100 is also needed, I did it for no mac computers.
- My local network has no DNS, but on the other side is discoverable.

Hope this helps.

printer -> WiFi -> turris -> Cable -> Mikro <- cable <- cave <- Wifi <- computer